# Tengo varios clientes y varios campos, me solicita los nombres de los campos, pero no los valores de cada campo por clientes

Tags: c++

por ejemplo, si pongo en que necesito 2 campos, me los solicita y yo pongo nombre y apellido. Pero después no entiendo porque no me solicita nombre del cliente 1, apellido del cliente 1 y nombre del cliente 2 y apellido del cliente 2.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string **clientes;
    int numeroClientes;
    int numeroCampos;
    string *campos;
    
    cout<< "¿Cuantos clientes desa almacenar?"<<"\n";
    cin >> numeroClientes;
    cout<<"¿Cuantos campos tiene cada clientes?"<<"\n";
    cin>>numeroCampos;
    campos = new string[numeroCampos];
    for (int i=0; i <numeroCampos; i++){
        cout << "Introduzca el nombre del campo "<< i +1<<"\n";
        cin >>campos[i];
    }
    for ( int j =0; j< numeroClientes; j++){
        clientes[j] = new string[numeroClientes];
    }
    for(int i=0; i < numeroClientes; i++){
        cout<< "Cliente"<< i + 1<< "\n";
        for (int j=0 ; j< numeroCampos; j++){
            cout<< "Introduzca"<<campos[j]<<"\n";
            cin>> clientes[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numeroClientes; i++){
        delete[]clientes[i];
    }
    delete []campos;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ( int j =0; j< numeroClientes; j++){
    clientes[j] = new string[numeroClientes];
}
```

Para poder rellenar `clientes[j]` antes tienes que haber reservado memoria en `clientes`:

```
clientes = new string*[numeroClientes];
```

Por otro lado, entiendo que tu idea es que cada cliente tenga tantos datos como  campos ha indicado el usuario un momento antes, luego la inicialización de `clientes[j]` es incorrecta. Hay que usar `numeroCampos` en vez de `numeroClientes`

```
for ( int j =0; j< numeroClientes; j++){
    clientes[j] = new string[numeroCampos];
}
```

Finalmente, te falta liberar la memoria de `clientes`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numeroClientes; i++){
    delete[]clientes[i];
}
delete[] clientes; // <<---
delete []campos;
```

Comment: uffffff me acabas de salvar. Ahora esta perfecto, muchisimas gracias <3

Comment: Acabo de publicar otro programa que me hace un pequeño fallo, si me puedes ayudar estaría fantastico. Merciii y ya se como marcar como solucionado heheheh